# Multiple sequential animations in infinite loop

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to have two animations applied to an element. These animations will execute sequentially infinite number of times. I want to use pure CSS without JS.

```css
@keyframes show {
  from,
  to {
    z-index: 100;
  }
}

@keyframes wait {
  from,
  to {
  }
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -100;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  animation: 1s show infinite, 1s wait infinite;
}

.block-a {
    background-color: red;
    animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
}

.block-b {
    background-color: purple;
    animation-delay: 1s, 2s;
}

.block-c {
    background-color: yellow; 
    animation-delay: 2s, 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block-a">1</div>
  <div class="block block-b">2</div>
  <div class="block block-c">3</div>
</div>
```

Here is my current solution on codepen: https://codepen.io/olafvolafka/pen/oNpPeqj

The issue is the animation stops after the last animation and doesn't repeat.

Comment: Maybe if they are different properties then this separation is logical, otherwise combination is the only way

Comment: both animation animate the same property, how you want the behavior to be?

Comment: Don't look at the properties it's only an example. I'm trying to achive to have two animations exectued sequentionally in infinite loop.

Comment: I've changed the example.

Comment: in your keyframes you should set the opacity,so fade one block in as you fade another block out.

Comment: But the first animation lasts only one second and then immediately repeats so the two animations are trampling over each other. Maybe animation-delay has been misunderstood? It only has effect once.

Comment: My animation is working as expected except it doesn't loop. It's not executed infinite number of times as I want to.

Comment: You can build an animation for each sub-part (blocks) and then build these into the keyframes of your parent animation, so you animate "show" and at keyframe `25%` for example trigger the sub animation (to run once) for the colour change.

Comment: It is executing an infinite number of times, but all the blocks are setting a high z index absolutlely all the time so you end up with block 3 showing.

Comment: I think we may get on a bit further if you could post an example with different settings. The second animation in your current code is doing nothing, and the first animation is constantly setting the z index high so basically after the first 3 seconds nothing seems to change.

Comment: The issue was I misunderstood css animations. I assumed multiple animations to are executed sequentially and not in parallel. So that's I used the wait keyframe to create a gap between iterations.

Comment: @Martin It doesn't and I knew this solution before. I asked how to make two animations applied to an element to play sequentially in a loop. The best answer to my question provided A Hawroth who points out that I misunderstood css animations.

Answer (score 0):

Here below you will see an implementation of [**A Haworth's Comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71855558/multiple-sequential-animations-in-infinite-loop/71856760#comment126978666_71855558) to enforce the `z-index` at the end of each animation iteration to return to the same value it was at the start (this case: -100).

Doing this is with the keyframe `50%` setting the z-index at the front (100)  . So that when each animation ends the properties are identical to when it began.

The animation is also set to cycle/repeat every 3 seconds rather than every 1 second as per your original code. This is that each iteration of the animation should run and complete before being called again; so 3 blocks means it runs for 3s. Each block having 1second as per your delay values in each blocks own class CSS code.

I have removed the `wait` animation because it simply didn't do anything. If you want an animation to wait there are various ways of doing this, not least with `keyframes` and [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay).

```css
@keyframes show {
  from {
  z-index: -100;
  }
  50% {
    z-index: 100;
  }
  to {
  z-index: -100;
  }
}


.block {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -100;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  animation: 3s show infinite;
}

.block-a {
    background-color: red;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.block-b {
    background-color: purple;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.block-c {
    background-color: yellow; 
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block-a">1</div>
  <div class="block block-b">2</div>
  <div class="block block-c">3</div>
</div>
```